# Как плавно при скролле страницы картинка становилась до вырезания

Tags: svg, svg-animation

1. элемент path в элементе clipPath вырезает фигуру в элементе  image
2. Как при скролле страницы вниз плавно отменялся элемент path в элементе clipPath
3. В итоге чтобы получилась картинка до вырезания ?
4. Как должно выглядеть можете посмотреть в ответе [Параллакс эффект для шапки сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086835/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

```html
<svg width='800' height='800'>
  <clipPath id='a'>
    <path 
       d="m 25.875145,-138.8886 c 4.413156,282.05606 0,278.0074 0,278.0074 136.448405,95.85897 215.705875,216.24853 399.390815,1.34956 l -2.20657,-278.00741 z"
       />
  </clipPath>  
  <image clip-path='url(#a)' width='500' height='500'  xlink:href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/909049/f1577d37-3f28-4cb6-ab6c-2cfca94456f9/s1200"/>
<animate
attributeName="d" 
dur="10s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Что значит плавно отменялся? Прозрачность?

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q как в ответе только svg ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086835/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: линейной интерполяцией подвигать точки в зависимости от скролла

Comment: @Stranger in the Q покажете как должно выглядеть ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/BaNprOZ?editors=1010

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я еще не дошел до такой функции как requestAnimationFrame :(((

Comment: можно по скроллу

Comment: @Stranger in the Q а можно сделать так только на svg ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся:

1) https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

2) https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js

3) https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js

К превиликому сожалению последний плагин платный по твоему примеру дэмо работы

**Пришлось скопипастить платный плагин что бы здесь заработало**

> смотреть на полный экран

```js
var Shape1 = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#path")[0];
var Shape1Path = Shape1.getAttribute("d");

TweenLite.set("svg", {
  visibility: "visible"
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: 0,
  yoyo: true,
  repeatDelay: 0,
  delay: 0
});

var changeVar = false;

function change() {
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (!changeVar) {
      if (scroll > 40) {
        tl.to(Shape1, 0.7, {
          morphSVG: {
            shape: "#path2"
          },
          stroke: "none",
          fill: "#716BFF",
          ease: Back.easeInOut
        });
        changeVar = true;
        console.log("scroll > 60 " + changeVar);
      }
    }

    if (changeVar) {
      if (scroll < 40) {
        tl.to(Shape1, 0.7, {
          morphSVG: {
            shape: Shape1Path
          },
          stroke: "none",
          fill: "#FF6B6B",
          ease: Back.easeInOut
        });
        changeVar = false;
        console.log(changeVar);
      }
    }
  });
}

setInterval(change, 500);
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#path2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 87 300 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  style="min-width: 100%;max-height: 80%;" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs>
<clipPath id="a">
<path id="path" d="M 6.2267948,146.95599 H 294.22677 c 3.32401,0 6.00001,2.67601 6.00001,6.00001 v 87.99998 c 0,3.32401 -2.676,6.00001 -6.00001,6.00001 H 150.28333 6.2267948 c -3.324005,0 -6.00000905,-2.676 -6.00000905,-6.00001 V 152.956 c 0,-3.324 2.67600405,-6.00001 6.00000905,-6.00001 z" fill="#f48024"/>
 </clipPath> 
   
 <path id="path2" d="M 6.7559615,146.95599 H 294.75594 c 3.32401,0 6.00001,2.67601 6.00001,6.00001 v 87.99998 c 0,3.32401 -2.676,6.00001 -6.00001,6.00001 0,0 -94.10438,40.43835 -143.94344,40.44345 -49.87535,0.005 -144.0565385,-40.44345 -144.0565385,-40.44345 -3.2002757,-0.89847 -6.00000908,-2.676 -6.00000908,-6.00001 V 152.956 c 0,-3.324 2.67600408,-6.00001 6.00000908,-6.00001 z" fill="#f48024"/>
</defs>
  
   <image clip-path='url(#a)' width='100%' height='500'  xlink:href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/909049/f1577d37-3f28-4cb6-ab6c-2cfca94456f9/s1200" x="0" y="0"/>
</svg>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var _gsScope="undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&"undefined"!=typeof global?global:this||window;(_gsScope._gsQueue||(_gsScope._gsQueue=[])).push(function(){"use strict";function y(e){window.console&&console.log(e)}function x(e,t,r,n,o,i,a,s,l){if(e!==s||t!==l){r=Math.abs(r),n=Math.abs(n);var h=o%360*Q,u=Math.cos(h),c=Math.sin(h),f=(e-s)/2,g=(t-l)/2,p=u*f+c*g,d=-c*f+u*g,v=r*r,b=n*n,M=p*p,m=d*d,A=M/v+m/b;1<A&&(v=(r=Math.sqrt(A)*r)*r,b=(n=Math.sqrt(A)*n)*n);var y=i===a?-1:1,x=(v*b-v*m-b*M)/(v*m+b*M);x<0&&(x=0);var N=y*Math.sqrt(x),S=r*d/n*N,z=-n*p/r*N,_=u*S-c*z+(e+s)/2,P=c*S+u*z+(t+l)/2,w=(p-S)/r,T=(d-z)/n,L=(-p-S)/r,q=(-d-z)/n,G=Math.sqrt(w*w+T*T),I=w,Y=(y=T<0?-1:1)*Math.acos(I/G)*E;G=Math.sqrt((w*w+T*T)*(L*L+q*q)),I=w*L+T*q;var B=(y=w*q-T*L<0?-1:1)*Math.acos(I/G)*E;!a&&0<B?B-=360:a&&B<0&&(B+=360);var C,X,R,V=function(e,t){var r,n,o,i,a,s,l=Math.ceil(Math.abs(t)/90),h=0,u=[];for(e*=Q,r=(t*=Q)/l,n=4/3*Math.sin(r/2)/(1+Math.cos(r/2)),s=0;s<l;s++)o=e+s*r,i=Math.cos(o),a=Math.sin(o),u[h++]=i-n*a,u[h++]=a+n*i,o+=r,i=Math.cos(o),a=Math.sin(o),u[h++]=i+n*a,u[h++]=a-n*i,u[h++]=i,u[h++]=a;return u}(Y%=360,B%=360),F=u*r,j=c*r,H=c*-n,O=u*n,D=V.length-2;for(C=0;C<D;C+=2)X=V[C],R=V[C+1],V[C]=X*F+R*H+_,V[C+1]=X*j+R*O+P;return V[V.length-2]=s,V[V.length-1]=l,V}}function f(e){var t,r,n,o,i,a,s,l,h,u,c,f,g,p=(e+"").replace(B,function(e){var t=+e;return t<1e-4&&-1e-4<t?0:t}).match(I)||[],d=[],v=0,b=0,M=p.length,m=2,A=0;if(!e||!isNaN(p[0])||isNaN(p[1]))return y("ERROR: malformed path data: "+e),d;for(t=0;t<M;t++)if(g=i,isNaN(p[t])?a=(i=p[t].toUpperCase())!==p[t]:t--,n=+p[t+1],o=+p[t+2],a&&(n+=v,o+=b),0===t&&(l=n,h=o),"M"===i)s&&s.length<8&&(--d.length,m=0),v=l=n,b=h=o,s=[n,o],A+=m,m=2,d.push(s),t+=2,i="L";else if("C"===i)(s=s||[0,0])[m++]=n,s[m++]=o,a||(v=b=0),s[m++]=v+ +p[t+3],s[m++]=b+ +p[t+4],s[m++]=v+=+p[t+5],s[m++]=b+=+p[t+6],t+=6;else if("S"===i)"C"===g||"S"===g?(u=v-s[m-4],c=b-s[m-3],s[m++]=v+u,s[m++]=b+c):(s[m++]=v,s[m++]=b),s[m++]=n,s[m++]=o,a||(v=b=0),s[m++]=v+=+p[t+3],s[m++]=b+=+p[t+4],t+=4;else if("Q"===i)u=n-v,c=o-b,s[m++]=v+2*u/3,s[m++]=b+2*c/3,a||(v=b=0),u=n-(v+=+p[t+3]),c=o-(b+=+p[t+4]),s[m++]=v+2*u/3,s[m++]=b+2*c/3,s[m++]=v,s[m++]=b,t+=4;else if("T"===i)u=v-s[m-4],c=b-s[m-3],s[m++]=v+u,s[m++]=b+c,u=v+1.5*u-n,c=b+1.5*c-o,s[m++]=n+2*u/3,s[m++]=o+2*c/3,s[m++]=v=n,s[m++]=b=o,t+=2;else if("H"===i)o=b,s[m++]=v+(n-v)/3,s[m++]=b+(o-b)/3,s[m++]=v+2*(n-v)/3,s[m++]=b+2*(o-b)/3,s[m++]=v=n,s[m++]=o,t+=1;else if("V"===i)o=n,n=v,a&&(o+=b-v),s[m++]=n,s[m++]=b+(o-b)/3,s[m++]=n,s[m++]=b+2*(o-b)/3,s[m++]=n,s[m++]=b=o,t+=1;else if("L"===i||"Z"===i)"Z"===i&&(n=l,o=h,s.closed=!0),("L"===i||.5<Math.abs(v-n)||.5<Math.abs(b-o))&&(s[m++]=v+(n-v)/3,s[m++]=b+(o-b)/3,s[m++]=v+2*(n-v)/3,s[m++]=b+2*(o-b)/3,s[m++]=n,s[m++]=o,"L"===i&&(t+=2)),v=n,b=o;else if("A"===i){for(f=x(v,b,+p[t+1],+p[t+2],+p[t+3],+p[t+4],+p[t+5],(a?v:0)+ +p[t+6],(a?b:0)+ +p[t+7]),r=0;r<f.length;r++)s[m++]=f[r];v=s[m-2],b=s[m-1],t+=7}else y("Error: malformed path data: "+e);return d.totalPoints=A+m,d}function N(e,t){var r,n,o,i,a,s,l,h,u,c,f,g,p,d,v=0,b=e.length,M=t/((b-2)/6);for(p=2;p<b;p+=6)for(v+=M;.999999<v;)r=e[p-2],n=e[p-1],o=e[p],i=e[p+1],a=e[p+2],s=e[p+3],l=e[p+4],h=e[p+5],u=r+(o-r)*(d=1/(Math.floor(v)+1)),u+=((f=o+(a-o)*d)-u)*d,f+=(a+(l-a)*d-f)*d,c=n+(i-n)*d,c+=((g=i+(s-i)*d)-c)*d,g+=(s+(h-s)*d-g)*d,e.splice(p,4,r+(o-r)*d,n+(i-n)*d,u,c,u+(f-u)*d,c+(g-c)*d,f,g,a+(l-a)*d,s+(h-s)*d),p+=6,b+=6,v--;return e}function a(e){var t,r,n,o,i="",a=e.length,s=100;for(r=0;r<a;r++){for(i+="M"+(o=e[r])[0]+","+o[1]+" C",t=o.length,n=2;n<t;n++)i+=(o[n++]*s|0)/s+","+(o[n++]*s|0)/s+" "+(o[n++]*s|0)/s+","+(o[n++]*s|0)/s+" "+(o[n++]*s|0)/s+","+(o[n]*s|0)/s+" ";o.closed&&(i+="z")}return i}function S(e){for(var t=[],r=e.length-1,n=0;-1<--r;)t[n++]=e[r],t[n++]=e[r+1],r--;for(r=0;r<n;r++)e[r]=t[r];e.reversed=!e.reversed}function g(e){var t,r=e.length,n=0,o=0;for(t=0;t<r;t++)n+=e[t++],o+=e[t];return[n/(r/2),o/(r/2)]}function z(e){var t,r,n,o=e.length,i=e[0],a=i,s=e[1],l=s;for(n=6;n<o;n+=6)i<(t=e[n])?i=t:t<a&&(a=t),s<(r=e[n+1])?s=r:r<l&&(l=r);return e.centerX=(i+a)/2,e.centerY=(s+l)/2,e.size=(i-a)*(s-l)}function _(e){for(var t,r,n,o,i,a=e.length,s=e[0][0],l=s,h=e[0][1],u=h;-1<--a;)for(t=(i=e[a]).length,o=6;o<t;o+=6)s<(r=i[o])?s=r:r<l&&(l=r),h<(n=i[o+1])?h=n:n<u&&(u=n);return e.centerX=(s+l)/2,e.centerY=(h+u)/2,e.size=(s-l)*(h-u)}function P(e,t){return t.length-e.length}function w(e,t){var r=e.size||z(e),n=t.size||z(t);return Math.abs(n-r)<(r+n)/20?t.centerX-e.centerX||t.centerY-e.centerY:n-r}function T(e,t){var r,n,o=e.slice(0),i=e.length,a=i-2;for(t|=0,r=0;r<i;r++)n=(r+t)%a,e[r++]=o[n],e[r]=o[1+n]}function p(e,t,r,n,o){var i,a,s,l,h=e.length,u=0,c=h-2;for(r*=6,a=0;a<h;a+=6)l=e[i=(a+r)%c]-(t[a]-n),s=e[1+i]-(t[a+1]-o),u+=Math.sqrt(s*s+l*l);return u}function L(e,t,r){var n,o,i,a=e.length,s=g(e),l=g(t),h=l[0]-s[0],u=l[1]-s[1],c=p(e,t,0,h,u),f=0;for(i=6;i<a;i+=6)(o=p(e,t,i/6,h,u))<c&&(c=o,f=i);if(r)for(n=e.slice(0),S(n),i=6;i<a;i+=6)(o=p(n,t,i/6,h,u))<c&&(c=o,f=-i);return f/6}function q(e,t,r){for(var n,o,i,a,s,l,h=e.length,u=99999999999,c=0,f=0;-1<--h;)for(l=(n=e[h]).length,s=0;s<l;s+=6)o=n[s]-t,i=n[s+1]-r,(a=Math.sqrt(o*o+i*i))<u&&(u=a,c=n[s],f=n[s+1]);return[c,f]}function G(e,t,r,n,o,i){var a,s,l,h,u=t.length,c=0,f=Math.min(e.size||z(e),t[r].size||z(t[r]))*n,g=999999999999,p=e.centerX+o,d=e.centerY+i;for(a=r;a<u&&!((t[a].size||z(t[a]))<f);a++)s=t[a].centerX-p,l=t[a].centerY-d,(h=Math.sqrt(s*s+l*l))<g&&(c=a,g=h);return h=t[c],t.splice(c,1),h}function s(e,t,r,n){var o,i,a,s,l,h,u,c=t.length-e.length,f=0<c?t:e,g=0<c?e:t,p=0,d="complexity"===n?P:w,v="position"===n?0:"number"==typeof n?n:.8,b=g.length,M="object"==typeof r&&r.push?r.slice(0):[r],m="reverse"===M[0]||M[0]<0,A="log"===r;if(g[0]){if(1<f.length&&(e.sort(d),t.sort(d),h=f.size||_(f),h=g.size||_(g),h=f.centerX-g.centerX,u=f.centerY-g.centerY,d===w))for(b=0;b<g.length;b++)f.splice(b,0,G(g[b],f,b,v,h,u));if(c)for(c<0&&(c=-c),f[0].length>g[0].length&&N(g[0],(f[0].length-g[0].length)/6|0),b=g.length;p<c;)f[b].size||z(f[b]),s=(a=q(g,f[b].centerX,f[b].centerY))[0],l=a[1],g[b++]=[s,l,s,l,s,l,s,l],g.totalPoints+=8,p++;for(b=0;b<e.length;b++)o=t[b],i=e[b],(c=o.length-i.length)<0?N(o,-c/6|0):0<c&&N(i,c/6|0),m&&!i.reversed&&S(i),(r=M[b]||0===M[b]?M[b]:"auto")&&(i.closed||Math.abs(i[0]-i[i.length-2])<.5&&Math.abs(i[1]-i[i.length-1])<.5?"auto"===r||"log"===r?(M[b]=r=L(i,o,0===b),r<0&&(m=!0,S(i),r=-r),T(i,6*r)):"reverse"!==r&&(b&&r<0&&S(i),T(i,6*(r<0?-r:r))):!m&&("auto"===r&&Math.abs(o[0]-i[0])+Math.abs(o[1]-i[1])+Math.abs(o[o.length-2]-i[i.length-2])+Math.abs(o[o.length-1]-i[i.length-1])>Math.abs(o[0]-i[i.length-2])+Math.abs(o[1]-i[i.length-1])+Math.abs(o[o.length-2]-i[0])+Math.abs(o[o.length-1]-i[1])||r%2)?(S(i),M[b]=-1,m=!0):"auto"===r?M[b]=0:"reverse"===r&&(M[b]=-1),i.closed!==o.closed&&(i.closed=o.closed=!1));return A&&y("shapeIndex:["+M.join(",")+"]"),M}}function d(e,t,r,n){var o=f(e[0]),i=f(e[1]);s(o,i,t||0===t?t:"auto",r)&&(e[0]=a(o),e[1]=a(i),"log"!==n&&!0!==n||y('precompile:["'+e[0]+'","'+e[1]+'"]'))}function o(e,t){var r,n,o,i,a,s,l,h=0,u=parseFloat(e[0]),c=parseFloat(e[1]),f=u+","+c+" ";for(r=.5*t/(.5*(o=e.length)-1),n=0;n<o-2;n+=2){if(h+=r,s=parseFloat(e[n+2]),l=parseFloat(e[n+3]),.999999<h)for(a=1/(Math.floor(h)+1),i=1;.999999<h;)f+=(u+(s-u)*a*i).toFixed(2)+","+(c+(l-c)*a*i).toFixed(2)+" ",h--,i++;f+=s+","+l+" ",u=s,c=l}return f}function r(e){var t=e[0].match(Y)||[],r=e[1].match(Y)||[],n=r.length-t.length;0<n?e[0]=o(t,n):e[1]=o(r,-n)}function v(t){return isNaN(t)?r:function(e){r(e),e[1]=function(e,t){if(!t)return e;var r,n,o,i=e.match(Y)||[],a=i.length,s="";for(r="reverse"===t?(n=a-1,-2):(n=(2*(parseInt(t,10)||0)+1+100*a)%a,2),o=0;o<a;o+=2)s+=i[n-1]+","+i[n]+" ",n=(n+r)%a;return s}(e[1],parseInt(t,10))}}function l(e,t){var r,n,o,i,a,s,l,h,u,c,f,g,p,d,v,b,M,m,A,y,x,N=e.tagName.toLowerCase(),S=.552284749831;return"path"!==N&&e.getBBox?(s=function(e,t){var r=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","path"),n=Array.prototype.slice.call(e.attributes),o=n.length;for(t=","+t+",";-1<--o;)-1===t.indexOf(","+n[o].nodeName+",")&&r.setAttributeNS(null,n[o].nodeName,n[o].nodeValue);return r}(e,"x,y,width,height,cx,cy,rx,ry,r,x1,x2,y1,y2,points"),"rect"===N?(i=+e.getAttribute("rx")||0,a=+e.getAttribute("ry")||0,n=+e.getAttribute("x")||0,o=+e.getAttribute("y")||0,c=(+e.getAttribute("width")||0)-2*i,f=(+e.getAttribute("height")||0)-2*a,r=i||a?"M"+(b=(d=(p=n+i)+c)+i)+","+(m=o+a)+" V"+(A=m+f)+" C"+[b,y=A+a*S,v=d+i*S,x=A+a,d,x,d-(d-p)/3,x,p+(d-p)/3,x,p,x,g=n+i*(1-S),x,n,y,n,A,n,A-(A-m)/3,n,m+(A-m)/3,n,m,n,M=o+a*(1-S),g,o,p,o,p+(d-p)/3,o,d-(d-p)/3,o,d,o,v,o,b,M,b,m].join(",")+"z":"M"+(n+c)+","+o+" v"+f+" h"+-c+" v"+-f+" h"+c+"z"):"circle"===N||"ellipse"===N?(h="circle"===N?(i=a=+e.getAttribute("r")||0)*S:(i=+e.getAttribute("rx")||0,(a=+e.getAttribute("ry")||0)*S),r="M"+((n=+e.getAttribute("cx")||0)+i)+","+(o=+e.getAttribute("cy")||0)+" C"+[n+i,o+h,n+(l=i*S),o+a,n,o+a,n-l,o+a,n-i,o+h,n-i,o,n-i,o-h,n-l,o-a,n,o-a,n+l,o-a,n+i,o-h,n+i,o].join(",")+"z"):"line"===N?r="M"+e.getAttribute("x1")+","+e.getAttribute("y1")+" L"+e.getAttribute("x2")+","+e.getAttribute("y2"):"polyline"!==N&&"polygon"!==N||(r="M"+(n=(u=(e.getAttribute("points")+"").match(Y)||[]).shift())+","+(o=u.shift())+" L"+u.join(","),"polygon"===N&&(r+=","+n+","+o+"z")),s.setAttribute("d",r),t&&e.parentNode&&(e.parentNode.insertBefore(s,e),e.parentNode.removeChild(e)),s):e}function b(e,t,r){var n,o,i="string"==typeof e;return(!i||(e.match(Y)||[]).length<3)&&((n=i?m.selector(e):e&&e[0]?e:[e])&&n[0]?(o=(n=n[0]).nodeName.toUpperCase(),t&&"PATH"!==o&&(n=l(n,!1),o="PATH"),e=n.getAttribute("PATH"===o?"d":"points")||"",n===r&&(e=n.getAttributeNS(null,"data-original")||e)):(y("WARNING: invalid morph to: "+e),e=!1)),e}var Q=Math.PI/180,E=180/Math.PI,I=/[achlmqstvz]|(-?\d*\.?\d*(?:e[\-+]?\d+)?)[0-9]/gi,Y=/(?:(-|-=|\+=)?\d*\.?\d*(?:e[\-+]?\d+)?)[0-9]/gi,M=/[achlmqstvz]/gi,B=/[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+e[\+\-]?\d+/gi,m=_gsScope._gsDefine.globals.TweenLite,A="Use MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath(elementOrSelectorText) to convert to a path before morphing.",C=_gsScope._gsDefine.plugin({propName:"morphSVG",API:2,global:!0,version:"0.8.6",init:function(e,t,r,n){var o,i,a,s,l,h,u,c;return"function"==typeof e.setAttribute&&("function"==typeof t&&(t=t(n,e)),l="POLYLINE"===(o=e.nodeName.toUpperCase())||"POLYGON"===o,"PATH"===o||l?(i="PATH"===o?"d":"points",("string"==typeof t||t.getBBox||t[0])&&(t={shape:t}),s=b(t.shape||t.d||t.points||"","d"==i,e),l&&M.test(s)?(y("WARNING: a <"+o+"> cannot accept path data. "+A),!1):(s&&((this._target=e).getAttributeNS(null,"data-original")||e.setAttributeNS(null,"data-original",e.getAttribute(i)),(a=this._addTween(e,"setAttribute",e.getAttribute(i)+"",s+"","morphSVG",!1,i,"object"==typeof t.precompile?function(e){e[0]=t.precompile[0],e[1]=t.precompile[1]}:"d"==i?(h=t.shapeIndex,u=t.map||C.defaultMap,c=t.precompile,u||c||h||0===h?function(e){d(e,h,u,c)}:d):v(t.shapeIndex)))&&(this._overwriteProps.push("morphSVG"),a.end=s,a.endProp=i)),!0)):(y("WARNING: cannot morph a <"+o+"> SVG element. "+A),!1))},set:function(e){var t;if(this._super.setRatio.call(this,e),1===e)for(t=this._firstPT;t;)t.end&&this._target.setAttribute(t.endProp,t.end),t=t._next}});C.pathFilter=d,C.pointsFilter=r,C.subdivideRawBezier=N,C.defaultMap="size",C.pathDataToRawBezier=function(e){return f(b(e,!0))},C.equalizeSegmentQuantity=s,C.convertToPath=function(e,t){"string"==typeof e&&(e=m.selector(e));for(var r=e&&0!==e.length?e.length&&e[0]&&e[0].nodeType?Array.prototype.slice.call(e,0):[e]:[],n=r.length;-1<--n;)r[n]=l(r[n],!1!==t);return r},C.pathDataToBezier=function(e,t){var r,n,o,i,a,s,l,h,u=f(b(e,!0))[0]||[],c=0;if(h=(t=t||{}).align||t.relative,i=t.matrix||[1,0,0,1,0,0],a=t.offsetX||0,s=t.offsetY||0,"relative"===h||!0===h?(a-=u[0]*i[0]+u[1]*i[2],s-=u[0]*i[1]+u[1]*i[3],c="+="):(a+=i[4],s+=i[5],h&&((h="string"==typeof h?m.selector(h):h&&h[0]?h:[h])&&h[0]&&(a-=(l=h[0].getBBox()||{x:0,y:0}).x,s-=l.y))),r=[],o=u.length,i)for(n=0;n<o;n+=2)r.push({x:c+(u[n]*i[0]+u[n+1]*i[2]+a),y:c+(u[n]*i[1]+u[n+1]*i[3]+s)});else for(n=0;n<o;n+=2)r.push({x:c+(u[n]+a),y:c+(u[n+1]+s)});return r}}),_gsScope._gsDefine&&_gsScope._gsQueue.pop()(),function(){"use strict";function e(){return(_gsScope.GreenSockGlobals||_gsScope).MorphSVGPlugin}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["TweenLite"],e):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&(require("../TweenLite.js"),module.exports=e())}();
</script>
```